# How can i hide the query string from the url using asp. Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I want to hide the query string from the url eg

```
http://example.com/productlist/id=2/pageno/3
```

My url should look like

```
http://example.com/productlist
```

Comment: simply don't use query string and pass your data using HTTP post

Comment: Can you please give an example as i am new to development

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass your data by HTTP POST. and don't use GET method.